# Nativescript IPhone X - How to "hide" home indicator behind two swipes to go to home screen

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using Nativescript Angular, (NS version 4.1) I am trying to implement a requirement for users to swipe up twice to go home on 
new IOS devices. Many mobile games have this functionality.

I know this has to do with `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` and
`preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` in the `ViewController`
Is there a way I can access these methods in Nativescript Angular?
Or just set a home indicator to require two swipes to go home?

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript

Comment: I found a workaround here https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3264#issuecomment-355476483

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3264) to allow iOS root view controller properties to be overridden. You have to actually override the `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` to `UIRectEdge.All` and as per Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887509-setneedsupdateofhomeindicatoraut) you have to update `setneedsupdateofhomeindicator` as well.

But if you try to access the these properties directly (e.g. `this.page.ios.prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden = true`), it will give you error `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.`

These is workaround discussed [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3264#issuecomment-355476483) where to you have copy the controller, modify the property and assign it back to owner.

```
const UIViewControllerImpl = new page.Page().ios.constructor as typeof UIViewController;

    const MyCustumUIViewController = UIViewController['extend'](Object.assign(
      {},
      // merge in the original methods
      ...UIViewControllerImpl.prototype,
      // add additional instance method / property overrides here, such as ...
      {
        preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() {
            console.log("This will be called from native!");
            return UIRectEdge.All;
        }
      }
    ));

    const performNavigation = frame.Frame.prototype['performNavigation'];
    frame.Frame.prototype['performNavigation'] = function(navigationContext:{entry:frame.BackstackEntry}) {
        const page = navigationContext.entry.resolvedPage;
        const controller = (<typeof UIViewController>MyCustumUIViewController).new();
        controller['_owner'] = new WeakRef(page);
        controller.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
        controller.view.backgroundColor = new color.Color("white").ios;
        page['_ios'] = controller;
        page.setNativeView(controller.view);
        performNavigation.call(this, navigationContext);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around, I did try this but couldn't get it working. He said its working with `tns-core-modules@3.4.0` I'm on `~4.0.0` also Im not even sure what file to place this code in, I tried `main.ts` and `app.component`. The code does run, but I never get the `"This will be called from native!"` console.log to show up. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks again!